# Why can't test JSON be cast to datetime?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Given this query

```
SELECT
    [InputEH].session, [InputEH].event, datediff(second, [InputEH].event_start, [InputEH].event_end) AS "duration"
INTO
    [SessionEventTable]
FROM
    [InputEH]
```

and this test json:

```
[{
    "session": "session123",
    "event": "access",
    "event_start": "2017-02-22T9:58:00.12345Z",
    "event_end": "2017-02-22T10:03:30.12345Z"
}]
```

the 'Test' function in ASA returns:

> Cannot cast value '2017-02-22T9:58:00.12345Z' to type 'datetime' in expression 'datediff ( second , [InputEH] . event_start , [InputEH] . event_end )'.

Am I missing something here? It seems this should work. As an aside, if I remove the quotes around `"2017-02-22T9:58:00.12345Z"`, it parses, but it doesn't work; I don't think this is right though, because the quotes *should* be there in the JSON input.

Comment: you have convert to date before using in function. cast it to date first than it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yikes - apparently `"2017-02-22T9:58:00.12345Z"` needs to be `"2017-02-22T09:58:00.12345Z"`. Problem solved.